# group similar queries in mysql

Tags: mysql, performance

I have page with lot of users (cca 80k) so I need to save execution time of every query. I was wondering if there is a way to group same queries and give just one result. For example: "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `user`" [obviously query that counts number of users on page :)] is executed every time the page is reloaded. My idea is that e.g. 10 users execute this query in same time, the first user queries DB and the others get only "outdated" cached result of first user. Is it possible to make this somehow in DB with some settings? 
Thanks for help.

M.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MySQL Reference Manual :: The MySQL Query Cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html)

[memcached - a distributed memory object caching system](http://memcached.org/)